# How do I move certain rows to column in R?

Tags: r

So I'm working on a data science project, but then ran into a problem.
Below is an example of my dataset. Let me walk you through briefly. (Please understand for showing you the dataset in Excel, since my dataset on RStudio is a little messy and also has some Korean letters in it.
"FoodCode" is the code of the sort of food which the subject(ID) ate in the past 24 hours.
 So you can see that subject ID 1 has eaten four different kinds of food in the past 24 hours.
"Intake" is the amount of the certain food that the subject ate.
"TotalIntake", obviously, is the total amount, sum of all food intakes of each subject. 
"Proportion" is simply "intake"/"totalintake".

[image]

Now, I want to convert the dataset that has "ID", "Proportion of FoodCode A", "Proportion of FoodCode B", ... and so far. (There are 20 different food codes). And of course, there will be no overlapping ID's in rows this time. 
I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks. :)

Comment: It would have been helpful if you would have created this sample dataset in R instead of excel and shared it with us using `dput` instead of image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Let me give it a try :)

Comment: You can save the above excel file as csv, read it in R using `df <- read.csv('excel_file.csv')` and do `dput(df)`.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I write the code? Do I have to use the snippet or something? Sorry I'm new to the field ;)

Comment: Well, the output from `dput(df)` is what we are interested in. You need to copy-paste that information here. Here is a good guide explaining how to share a reproducible example.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269. Also it is better to show your expected output for dataset shared.

Comment: Looks like you want to reshape your data, from long to wide. Another term for this task is "pivoting" using Excel parlance. tidyr package has the `pivot_wider` function. There are literally hundreds of posts on SO here about how to do that. Try searching first, then come back if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  dplyr::select(ID,FoodCode, Proportion) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "FoodCode", values_from = "Proportion")
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  ID    A     B     C     D     E    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     0.208 0.208 0.417 0.167 NA   
2 2     0.059 0.588 NA    0.294 0.059
```

If you need to replace those `NA`s with `0` your can use `na_replace`:

```
data %>% 
  dplyr::select(ID,FoodCode, Proportion) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "FoodCode", values_from = "Proportion") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-ID),list(~replace_na(.,0)))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  ID    A     B     C     D     E    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     0.208 0.208 0.417 0.167 0    
2 2     0.059 0.588 0     0.294 0.059
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2"), 
    FoodCode = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "D", "E"), Intake = c("100", 
    "100", "200", "80", "20", "200", "100", "20"), TotalIntake = c("480", 
    "480", "480", "480", "340", "340", "340", "340"), Proportion = c("0.208", 
    "0.208", "0.417", "0.167", "0.059", "0.588", "0.294", "0.059"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please excuse any errors in the data as I used optical character recognition on your image.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing here what you are after as your question is not easy to correctly interpret. Here is my reading of it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,2),
  FoodCode = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "D", "E"),
  Intake = c(100, 100, 200, 80, 20, 200, 100, 20)
)

data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(IntakeTotal = sum(Intake)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Proportion = Intake / IntakeTotal)

summary <- data %>%  
  select(-Intake, -IntakeTotal) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_from = Proportion,
              names_from = FoodCode)
```

The columns IntakeTotal and Proportion can be easily calculated from the other columns. Then my reading of what you wanted is to use the `pivot-wider` function to reshape the object into a wide format:

Initial object `data`:

```
> data
# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID FoodCode Intake
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 A           100
2     1 B           100
3     1 C           200
4     1 D            80
5     2 A            20
6     2 B           200
7     2 D           100
8     2 E            20
```

After re-creating the IntakeTotal and Proportion columns:

```
> data
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     ID FoodCode Intake IntakeTotal Proportion
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 A           100         480     0.208 
2     1 B           100         480     0.208 
3     1 C           200         480     0.417 
4     1 D            80         480     0.167 
5     2 A            20         340     0.0588
6     2 B           200         340     0.588 
7     2 D           100         340     0.294 
8     2 E            20         340     0.0588
```

And finally after changing shape to a wide format. Is this what you were after?

```
> summary
# A tibble: 2 x 6
     ID      A     B      C     D       E
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 0.208  0.208  0.417 0.167 NA     
2     2 0.0588 0.588 NA     0.294  0.0588
```